# running website with no http show different content

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, virtualhost

Im running 3 sites in one server the same IP in Ubuntu/Apache using vhost.
I bought an SSL certificate and installed it in one of my sites successfully. The problem is when I run the site with no https it shows content from my other site.

Ex.

- www.aaaaa.com
- www.bbbbb.com (SSL)
- www.ccccc.com

when I run **https**://bbbbb.com there is no problem but
when I run **http**://bbbbb.com it shows the content of www.aaaaa.com

I know the ssl is working correctly coz I have tested it sslchecker.

This is the first time I installed SSL, I hope someone knows something about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok just got the Answer from this link

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9821/38/redirect-to-https-on-apache

You just need to Redirect HTTPS on Apache. Solution is I added vhost port 80 on my conf file in apache to redirect it to https when accessing the site with no https.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com.ca
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com/example.ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.com/example.ca.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```